# How to count unique rows in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

I already know how to count unique rows using deprecated Query API like that:

```
  self.session.query(table).distinct().count()
```

But how to do this using currently supported ORM api? (https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm)

`select(func.count()).select_from(select(table).distinct()))` does not work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
class Record(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'records'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String)


with Session(engine) as session:
    count_of_unique_record_titles = session.execute(select(func.count(Record.title.distinct()))).scalar()
```